# How to merge (inner) two columns of a dataframe with pandas/python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe containing two columns; A_ID and R_ID.

I want to update R_ID to only contain values that are also in A_ID, the rest should be deleted (also NaN). The values should stay at the same position/index. I get that this is an inner join but with my proposed solution I got several problems.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A_ID': ['1E2', '1E3', '1E4', '1E5'], 'R_ID': ['1E7',[np.nan],[np.nan],"1E4",]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I tried

```
df_A_ID = df[["A_ID"]]
df_R_ID = df[["R_ID"]]
new_df = pd.merge(df_A_ID, df_R_ID, how='inner', left_on='A_ID', right_on ='R_ID', right_index=True)
```

and

```
new_df = pd.concat([dataset_A_ID, dataset_R_ID],join="inner")
```

But with the first option I get an "You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns" error, even though both columns are of d.types object and with the second one i get an empty DataFrame.

My expected output would be the same dataframe as before but with R_ID only containing values that are also in the column A_ID, at the same index/position:

```
data = {'A_ID': ['1E2', '1E3', '1E4', '1E5'], 'R_ID': [[np.nan],[np.nan],[np.nan],"1E4",]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: kindly share your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `NaN` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) if no match columns compared by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
#solution working with scalar NaNs
data = {'A_ID': ['1E2', '1E3', '1E4', '1E5'], 'R_ID': ['1E7',np.nan,np.nan,"1E4",]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
  A_ID R_ID
0  1E2  1E7
1  1E3  NaN
2  1E4  NaN
3  1E5  1E4

df['R_ID'] = df['R_ID'].where(df["R_ID"].isin(df["A_ID"]))
print(df)
  A_ID R_ID
0  1E2  NaN
1  1E3  NaN
2  1E4  NaN
3  1E5  1E4
```

Or:

```
df.loc[~df["R_ID"].isin(df["A_ID"]), 'R_ID'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my example, the "matching" values like 1E4 in this case do not necessarily have the same index. Its more a "if VLOOKUP = TRUE than keep, otherwhise NaN" thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin`:

```
df['R_ID'] = df['R_ID'].loc[df['R_ID'].isin(df['A_ID'])]
```

```
>>> df
  A_ID R_ID
0  1E2  NaN
1  1E3  NaN
2  1E4  NaN
3  1E5  1E4
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my example, the "matching" values like 1E4 in this case do not necessarily have the same index. Its more a "if VLOOKUP = TRUE than keep, otherwhise NaN" thing. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielSchloß, I updated my answer too. (why '[nan]'?)

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
df_A_ID = df[["A_ID"]].astype(dtype=pd.StringDtype())
df_R_ID = df[["R_ID"]].astype(dtype=pd.StringDtype()).reset_index()
temp_df = pd.merge(df_A_ID, df_R_ID, how='inner', left_on='A_ID', right_on ='R_ID').set_index('index')

df.loc[~(df_R_ID.isin(temp_df[['R_ID']])['R_ID']).fillna(False),'R_ID'] = [np.nan]
```

Output

```
  A_ID R_ID
0  1E2  NaN
1  1E3  NaN
2  1E4  1E4
3  1E5  NaN
```

Comment: Yes but I would expect the output to be the original df, just with the R_IDs that are not in column A_ID as NaN.

Comment: I have updated my answer if I understood you correctly.